# How to add the banner area in the sliding menu in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, slider

[image]

I am currently using the https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu sliding menu library.

From a working example : https://github.com/baruckis/Android-SlidingMenuImplementation It use a list fragment on the left side menu.  The problem is, I would like to add a banner area at the top of the list, are there any way to achieve that ? (like the facebook one they have search box and user info at the top of the list)

I tried using add header view in the list fragment but I would prefer the area is not slidable and fix at the top. Thanks

The below code is the list fragment class where the R.layout.sliding_menu_holo_light_list is a listview , so it seems I can not customize it

```
public class SlidingMenuListFragment extends ListFragment {
    protected List<SlidingMenuListItem> slidingMenuList;
    private SlidingMenuBuilderBase slidingMenuBuilderBase;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // We set here a custom layout which uses holo light theme colors.
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_menu_holo_light_list, null);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // We get a list from our specially created list data class.
            slidingMenuList = SlidingMenuList.getSlidingMenu(getActivity());
            if (slidingMenuList == null)
                    return;

            // We pass our taken list to the adapter.
            SlidingMenuListAdapter adapter = new SlidingMenuListAdapter(
                            getActivity(), R.layout.sliding_menu_holo_light_list_row, slidingMenuList);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // We could define item click actions here, but instead we want our builder
    // to be responsible for that.
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            l.setSelection(position);
            SlidingMenuListItem item = slidingMenuList.get(position);
            slidingMenuBuilderBase.onListItemClick(item);
    }

    // We can not provide a builder as an argument inside a fragment
    // constructor, so that is why we have separate method for that.
    public void setMenuBuilder(SlidingMenuBuilderBase slidingMenuBuilderBase) {
            this.slidingMenuBuilderBase = slidingMenuBuilderBase;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Each implementation of the Navigation Drawer has its own intricacies however with most of them allow you to inflate an entire layout meaning that you can use a linear layout as the parent and include your list fragment (or whatever else you want to use).  I didn't read in to the provided library however I would recommend looking at googles implementation of the [navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

As a note: I haven't actually tried googles implementation, when I implemented a navigation drawer it was before they added this to the support library so I made my own.